# union de 2 tablas en laravel no me trae las relaciones

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Tengo dos tablas, `nentregas` y `compras` a las cuales les estoy haciendo una consulta con un union, ya que necesito que ambas se vean en una sola lista:

```
public function index()
{
    
    $notas = Nentrega::select('id', 'proveedor_id', 'user_id', 'fecha_compra', 'total', 'tasabs', 'estado','objtype') //shows 'null' because the 'debit' column does not exist in this table
        ->OrderBy('fecha_compra', 'DESC')
        ->where('estado', 'PENDIENTE')->with('detallenentregas');

    $compras = Compra::select('id', 'proveedor_id', 'user_id', 'fecha_compra', 'total', 'tasabs', 'estado','objtype') //shows the value of the column 'debit' table 'user_transaction'
        ->where('estado', 'PENDIENTE')

        ->union($notas)
        ->OrderBy('fecha_compra', 'DESC')
        ->get();

    return view('admin.compra.index', compact('compras'));
}
```

El problema es que no me está trayendo las relaciones de las tablas y me da un error `foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given` que sale a la altura de:

```
 <td>
       @foreach ($compra->detallenentregas as $detallecompra)
              {{$detallecompra->cantidad}} <br>
       @endforeach
 </td>
```

Pero al llamar a la relación `$compra->detallecompras` que tiene mi tabla de compras, esa sí me funciona, ¿qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quien pueda interesar, lo resolví utilizando un `merge`

```
public function index()
{
    
    $notas = Nentrega::
        where('estado', 'PENDIENTE')
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->get();

    $facturas = Compra::
        where('estado', 'PENDIENTE')
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->get();

    
    $compras = $facturas->merge($notas);

    return view('admin.compra.index', compact('compras'));
}
```